# Curry Howard correspondence in Coq

Tags: coq, curry-howard

By Curry Howard correspondence, all theorems and lemmas are types and proof objects are values. As an example:

```
Theorem test:  0 <= 0.
Proof.
  omega. Qed.
```

When I do, Check test. Coq's output is:

```
test
     : 0 <= 0
```

But when I check the type of "<=", it is nat -> nat -> Prop. That means (0 <= 0) is of type Prop. Does this mean that the type 'test' is a subtype of Prop? In general, are theorem and lemma identifiers subtypes of Prop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test : 0 <= 0` and `0 <= 0 : Prop`, as you said. In the terminology of the Curry-Howard correspondence, `0 <= 0` is a type/theorem statement, and `test` is a value of that type/proof of that theorem.

There isn't any subtyping involved in this example. Subtyping is a relationship between two types; when `Cat <: Animal` (cat is a subtype of animal), it means all objects of type cat *are also* of type animal: `x : Cat` implies `x : Animal`.

Coq has one relatively simple form of subtyping, between type universes. The simplest example is that `Prop` is a subtype of `Type`. You can see this by using `Check` to confirm that `0 <= 0 : Prop` and also `0 <= 0 : Type`.

Comment: '0 <= 0 : Prop' : here both LHS and RHS are types, no? So subtyping?

Comment: They are both types, but the relationship between them is "has-type", not subtyping. They seem really similar (and we use similar-looking notation), but they behave differently.

Comment: If I am correct, the has-type relation requires a value of the type on LHS and the type on RHS as in (n: nat). In above (0 <= 0) is a 'value' which has type 'Prop'; also it is a type? So a type has type 'Prop'? Am I correct?

Comment: You are right that some types like `0 <= 0`, `True`, `False`, `p \/ q` or `x = y` have type `Prop`, but not all types have type `Prop`, to begin with `Prop` itself which has type `Prop : Type`, but also `nat : Set` (`Set` is an alias for a specific case of `Type`).